# Why do we need map function in jq?

Tags: jq

I am just playing with `jq`. Please check the following outputs.

```
% FRUITS='[
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "color": "green",
    "price": 1.2
  },
  {
    "name": "banana",
    "color": "yellow",
    "price": 0.5
  },
  {
    "name": "kiwi",
    "color": "green",
    "price": 1.25
  }
]'
% echo $FRUITS
% echo $FRUITS | jq .
% echo $FRUITS | jq '[.[].color] | unique'
[
  "green",
  "yellow"
]

% echo $FRUITS | jq 'map(.color) | unique'
[
  "green",
  "yellow"
]

% echo $FRUITS | jq '. | map(has("name"))'
[
  true,
  true,
  true
]
% echo $FRUITS | jq '[.[] | has("name")]'
[
  true,
  true,
  true
]
```

Here, `jq '[.[].color] | unique'` give the same output as `jq 'map(.color) | unique'`

`jq '[.[] | has("name")]'` give the same output as `jq '. | map(has("name"))'`

I am not understanding what is the purpose and difference of the map function.

Comment: `map` is not something special, it is just a placeholder like you said - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L3

Comment: The source code contains a file called [`builtin.jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq), which contains some built-in functions for convenience, written in `jq` itself. On line 3 you can see how `map` is defined: `def map(f): [.[] | f];`.

Comment: @Inian Your comment seems most accurate. are you going to answer?

Comment: Its same as pmf's. I don't think it deserves an answer on its own. You could self answer it, if you want with some additional examples or leave it be.

Comment: `map` is not something special, it is just a placeholder github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq#L3 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's absolutely no difference between `[ .[] | ... ]` vs `map( ... )`. You can [see](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/cff5336ec71b6fee396a95bb0e4bea365e0cd1e8/src/builtin.jq#L3) this in jq's source.

Languages often provide syntactical shortcuts to make certain tasks simpler than by using general tools. This is known as [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar).

While `map` is not a special syntax, the same concept applies. It's a nice way to do something that's commonly needed.

It also imports a [well-known concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)) to jq. While map originated in functional programming languages, it has been adopted by a very large number of languages (sometimes under a different name).

- Lisp: maplist, mapcar
- Perl: map
- JavaScript: Array.prototype.map
- Python: map
- C#: Enumerable.Select
- C++: std::transform
- etc